# Generate a barcode with alternate text

Tags: barcode

I currently need to create barcodes in bulk, preferably in the "Code 39" format. This site http://www.barcodez.net/index.php is doing almost exactly what I want it, but I need one other feature. As you can see in the barcode below, it includes the code under the barcode. I want the text underneath to be different than the information encoded in the barcode (apply the same prefix to each code). An alternative would be to include a header or footer. Is there some way to accomplish this, preferably still in bulk?

Ex:

*information encoded in barcode:* 3

*text underneath:* InventorySys 3

-----Next barcode-----

*information encoded in barcode:* 4

*text underneath:* InventorySys 4

[image]

Comment: What did you already try? At which precise part of your programs do you get stuck?

Comment: er, i think maybe you misunderstood my question, though i don't know how to restate it. I am not trying to make a program

Comment: So you need a barcode generator which produce barcodes with **inconsistent encoded and readable parts**?!? I guess you need modify an open source generator or batch merge images of standard code and your prefix/suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Seagull Scientific](http://www.seagullscientific.com/) as they have label software called Bartender that specialises in barcodes.  There are lots of options provided.  Generally the online barcode generators will do exactly what you have experienced.  That is they will write your text underneath the barcode image.  That is standard practice.  Anything non-standard will require special software or perhaps a barcode font on your printer.